# Outlook JS API: Office.Recurrence.setStartTime uses UTC for OWA and Recurrence timezone for Windows Client

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

```
const newRec: Office.Recurrence = cloneDeep(EventRecurrence);
newRec.seriesTime.setStartTime(stLocal.getUTCHours(), stLocal.getUTCMinutes());
```

In (PlatformType is OfficeOnline) .setStartTime adjusts the hours assuming UTC but in the Windows and Mac Outlook clients it does not adjust the hours based on timezone.

e.g. .setStartTime(11,0) on OWA computes 6am and Win/Mac clients computes 11am.

workaround:

```
          const newRec: Office.Recurrence = cloneDeep(EventRecurrence);
          if (GetOutlookPlatform === Office.PlatformType.OfficeOnline) {
            newRec.seriesTime.setStartTime(stLocal.getUTCHours(), stLocal.getUTCMinutes());
          } else {
            newRec.seriesTime.setStartTime(stLocal.getHours(), stLocal.getMinutes());
          }
```

Comment: I'm able to reproduce this as well. Per [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.recurrence?view=outlook-js-preview#seriesTime), the recurrence should respect the calendar item's time zone or the recurrenceTimeZone parameter (if specified), rather than default to UTC. We'll take a closer look at why the APIs behavior in OWA isn't matching the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this issue regarding Recurrence. It has been put on our backlog. We, unfortunately, have no timelines to share at this point